# Loop in loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I have a data set:

```
Date    c00  c01  c02   c03
1        3    4   10    12
2        2    5   NULL  8
3       NULL NULL 20    13
```

The file name is capacity.intensity and I'm trying to replace the NULL with 0 by the following code:

```
for(i in capacity.intensity [1:3,])
{
  for(j in capacity.intensity [,2:5])
  {capacity.intensity [i,j]<- 
           ifelse(as.character(unlist(capacity.intensity [i,j])) == "NULL", "0", 
          as.character(unlist(capacity.intensity [i,j])))
  }
}
```

but I am getting the error

> Error in Summary.factor(c(32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L,  : 
>     min not meaningful for factors

when I traceback it.

Please kindly tell me how can I solve this problem?

Comment: How are you getting this data into R? Seems like those "NULL" values are messing things up. Should they be interpreted as missing values? It would probably be better to set `na.strings="NULL"` during the `read.table` assuming that's how you are important the data. A string "NULL" is a lot different than a "true" `NULL` value.

Comment: a `dput(capacity.intensity)` would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `revalue` from `plyr`:

```
sapply(capacity.intensity,
       function(x)revalue(factor(x),c(NULL=0)))

    Date c00 c01 c02  c03 
[1,] "1"  "3" "4" "10" "12"
[2,] "2"  "2" "5" "0"  "8" 
[3,] "3"  "0" "0" "20" "13"
```

where :

```
capacity.intensity <- 
read.table(text='Date    c00  c01  c02   c03
1        3    4   10    12
2        2    5   NULL  8
3       NULL NULL 20    13',header=TRUE)
```

capacity.intensity is a data.frame of mixed integers and factors.

Comment: But what kind of object is `capacity.intensity` that can hold a NULL value like that? All the values must be factors and the NULL is a level of NULL rather than a "proper" NULL value

Comment: @MrFlick I add some details about the data. The NULL is factor level so the use of `revalue` and `factor`'to coerce integer column).

Comment: This is a R data set.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with a "NULL" factor level that you want to change to zero, you can do

```
> as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) {
      x <- as.character(x)
      x[x == "NULL"] <- 0; x
  }))
#   Date c00 c01 c02 c03
# 1    1   3   4  10  12
# 2    2   2   5   0   8
# 3    3   0   0  20  13
```

where `df` is the data. Or you could write a little function you can keep and use again later.

```
> foo <- function(x, from, to) {
      x <- as.character(x)
      x[x == from] <- to
      x
  }
> as.data.frame(lapply(df, foo, "NULL", 0))
#   Date c00 c01 c02 c03
# 1    1   3   4  10  12
# 2    2   2   5   0   8
# 3    3   0   0  20  13
```